# ローカルで操作中のブランチに別のブランチをpullしたら、ブランチの切り替えができなくなった。pull前の状態に戻したい。

Tags: git, gitlab

ローカルでブランチAを操作中なのですが、このブランチに対して誤ってmasterブランチをpullしたら競合が発生し、他のブランチに切り変えることができなくなりました。ローカルのブランチAは事前に一度リモートにpush済みです。

pullはVSCodeの「指定元からプル」を行いました。

現在ローカルで他のブランチに切り替えようとすると以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
Git: you need to resolve your current index first
```

リモートにあるブランチAの状態に戻したい（pullする前の状態に戻したい）のですが、

- `git reset --head HEAD`
- `git merge --abort`

のいずれかのコマンドを叩けば良いのでしょうか。

[【git】マージしたけどやっぱりやめたい時のやり方4種類 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/chihiro/items/5dd671aa6f1c332986a7)

この記事も参考にしたのですが、最後の方に「一度pushなどを行って、ほかの開発者に公開されているコミットを取り消すことは絶対にしてはいけません。」とあるので少し不安になりました。

ちなみにこのブランチは自分しか触ってません。

ご存知の方、ご回答をよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決

```
git merge --abort
```

で解決しました！